# Why no libc* when I use gcc to link main.c?

Tags: gcc, ld

If I have:

```
$ gcc -v -lm -lc math.o 2> logg
```

There are no libc or libm in the resulting link logg. Is that normal?

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 4.9.1-16ubuntu6) 4.9.1
```

Comment: Where are you expecting to find them?

Comment: So gcc -v displays details of the commands gcc uses at the various compilation stages, ld being the relevant stage here. Does this not show the libraries used by the linker?

Comment: It may show them in `-lc` format instead of expanded into full filenames like `libc.so`